# Upgrade Angular 9 to 10 Problem angular-datatables dependencies

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I have project angular 9, with angular-datatables, but when i upgrade to angular 10 have an eror
angular-datatables has an incompatible peer dependency to "angular/core"...

[image]

how to solve this?

Comment: This issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10875#issue-323392086

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ng update @angular/core --next --force`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the packages you are using might be using an older version of angular.

> First Identify the packages and check if you have a latest version
> supporting angular 10. This would be the cleanest way to get rid of
> this error.

If that is not possible you can follow the force update way. But there are chances that the packages might break in some places.